# Check if incremented by 10 c++

Tags: c++, modulus

I need to check of a number is incremented by 10 (70, 20, 110)

example:
input: (74, 21, 105)
output: false

input: (70, 20, 110)
output: true

I have tried `if(num % 10 == 1)`

Comment: Try `if(num % 10 == 0)` and in future please put a bit more effort into working things like this out for yourself.

Comment: 1. there is no question, 2. read on what `%` does.100%10 equals 0

Comment: I suggest *subtracting* the numbers, subtract the first from the second.  If the difference between two numbers is 10, then the second is incremented by 10.

Comment: All of the members of `(70, 20, 110)` are _divisible_ by 10, but why should that list pass a test called _incremented_ by 10?  What do you think "increment" means?

Answer (score 2):

The [*remainder operator* (`%`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Remainder) is indeed what you're looking for.

> The binary operator `%` yields the remainder of the division of the first operand by the second (after usual arithmetic conversions).

The remainder you're looking for is **zero**, not one. Therefore the correct check is:

```
if(num % 10 == 0)
```